# WordPress image path in js file

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm creating WP Theme, I'm using slick slider and for nextArrow, prevArrow in main.js file, can't take image url path.

```
 prevArrow: '<img class="a-left control-c prev slick-prev" src="img/left-arrow.png">',
 nextArrow: '<img class="a-left control-c prev slick-prev" src="img/right-arrow.png">',
```

Also i have created one var in js

```
var templateUrl = '<?= get_bloginfo("template_url"); ?>';
```

and then, I have called this variable in this form:

```
prevArrow: '<img class="a-left control-c prev slick-prev" src="' + templateUrl + '/img/left-arrow.png">',
```

but did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could avoid hardcoding the full path by setting a JS variable in the header of your template, before `wp_head()` is called, holding the template URL. Like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var templateUrl = '<?= get_bloginfo("template_url"); ?>';
</script>
```

And use that variable for example to set the background (I realize you know how to do this, I only include these details in case it helps others):

```
Reset.style.background = " url('"+templateUrl+"/images/searchfield_clear.png') ";
```

Answer (score 1):

use something like this in your template:

```
var templateUrl = '<?= get_template_directory_uri(); ?>';
```

that will get you full url to theme directory, and then add your subdirectory "/img/.."